# pseudo-global variables/objects inside particular classes

Tags: python, global

Code below demonstrates how I can initialize a "Deal" of a shuffled list of n=3 cards using an RNG I have named `rndm()` here that I want to use. My problem is how to position and use the "global" variables `seed` when the implied "global" `hand` really has to be inside a `class` because there are multiple `hand`s really, owned by individual users whose records are in the ndb class Account. I want `seed` to be global to a particular user, but I don't know how to associate each user with **her** `seed`. I have marked as "#important*****" the aspect of `hand` that I think is required to make it all work.

```
M = -1+2**31
A = 7**5
rseed = random.randrange(M) 

class Account(ndb.Model):


    seed  = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=rseed)
    oldseed  = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=None)


hand = Account()
hand.oldseed = hand.seed

def rndm(z):
   global M
   global A
   global seed
   seed = (A*seed)%M
   temp = seed*z
   return math.floor(temp/M)

def deal(n):
    temp = []
    for i in list(range(n)):
       temp.append(int(rndm(M)))
    seed=int(seed)
    global seed

seed = hand.seed           #important*******
hand.oldseed = seed           #important*******

def begin():
    deal(3)
    global seed
    hand.seed = seed
    print 'hand.oldseed '+str(hand.oldseed)
    print 'hand.seed    '+str(hand.seed)
    hand.put() # saves hand.seed and hand.oldseed
begin()

seed = hand.oldseed      #redoes previous run
hand.oldseed = seed
begin()
```

So I think my problem is that in my real code I want `hand` to not be "global" but in a class, and I don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: Is this your question: How to write a [python class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) with `hand` as an instance variable?

Comment: I think so. If I put `hand` in a class then it is no longer available to assign a value to the global `seed`, is it?

Comment: Why do you need a global seed? Also, hand will hold a reference to Account instance. So, seed is accessible via hand.

Comment: `seed` is needed in Account to initialize `rseed` for the default value of ` hand.seed` . That default value is an initial random seed for the RNG for each instance of Account. I understand that `hand` will hold a reference to `Account` instance, in your words, but first `hand` must have a seed which is global. And in my code `hand` seems to need to be `global`, at least that's what my experimentation suggests. It's like a chicken and egg problem, they both need to be first.

Comment: I'm finding it a bit hard to follow your code. If you can share a requirements doc, I might be able to help. Good luck.

Comment: I think I understand your points, now. If I just move the 2 lines like `hand = Account()` and `seed = hand.seed` from their global position to the beginning of `begin()` they will be inside begin as if begin was a class, and also they will  "see" and update the global values as needed.I still need `global seed` in `deal()` but not in `begin()` . Yes!